# Assertionerror - Display only error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

I've the folowing code and want to print only the error (No data found, symbol may be delisted).

Is it possible write better code?

```
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
import sys
try:
    quoteinfo = si.get_data("badticker",start_date = "01/01/2022", end_date = "04/30/2022")
    print(quoteinfo)
except AssertionError as e:
    if (  "symbol may be delisted" in str(e)) :
        print ('Ticker is invalid')
    else:
        print(e)
```

Exception :

> {'chart': {'result': None, 'error': {'code': 'Not Found',
> 'description': 'No data found, symbol may be delisted'}}}

Comment: It looks like AssertionError is not being raised...

Comment: @JohnGordon, AssertionError  is being raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks mostly fine. However:

1. I'd check against the full string: `'No data found, symbol may be delisted'` to be on the save side,
2. the brackets in the `if`-statement are redundant,
3. you got unused imports,
4. your code could also use some formatting.

```
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si

try:
    quoteinfo = si.get_data("badticker", start_date="01/01/2022", end_date="04/30/2022")
except AssertionError as e:
    if "No data found, symbol may be delisted" in str(e):
        print("Ticker is invalid")
    else:
        print(e)
```

Comment: thanks. I was just wondering, if there is a simple way to check the error directly without string search.

Comment: @nsivakr It's as good as it well get. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/atreadw1492/yahoo_fin/blob/master/yahoo_fin/stock_info.py) the error is just the json dump in an assertation error.